# SQL injection on registration form

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I would like to ask, if an SQL injection on a registration form is dangerous in any way. I managed to inject this

```
ZAP OR 1=1--
```

It gives me the 302 error. I registered an account using this injection as Used Id and Password.
Could this be a bug or not? I am interested for a bug bounty.

Comment: Are you serious? ___is an SQL injection on a registration form dangerous___ Well of course it is, they are dangeruos EVERYWHERE

Comment: SQL injection is dangerous, full stop. If you managed to inject SQL in the sign up form then you can usually compromise the whole DB in not a lot of time. Definitely a red flag, I'd warn the site moderator.

Comment: A 302 status code is usually not an error, its a redirect.

Comment: *"I would like to ask, if an SQL injection on a registration form is dangerous in any way"* *"I am interested for a bug bounty"* So a ethical hacker/cracker does not know the impact of the a SQL injection or are you a scriptkiddie instead? .. The other comments are true you can use the 302 http status to blindly attack the database, to bruteforce database names, tables names, columns where the MySQL user has access to.. if you know that you can bruteforce valid application usernames and passwords if anny.

Comment: I asked if my injection (ZAP OR 1=1--)can have any impact, because as you can see it lacks the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is dangerous. Extremely dangerous. Let's assume you have a table called users and inject the following:

```
'; delete from users where '' = '
```

Then all your users will be removed. But in your case the text you have written is

> ZAP OR 1=1

which is invalid SQL. Assuming the system expects a textual data. In that case it ends up enclosing it into apostrophes. The real test would be

> ZAP' OR 1=1